# Linux kernel (x86-64) assembly for decoding `struct pt_regs` into registers in syscall

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64, system-calls, calling-convention

I have read this [LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/750536/) on `struct pt_regs`-based syscall calling for x86-64.

I don't understand the way `struct pt_regs *` is decoded into registers.

Indeed, `%rdi` holds the address of `struct pt_regs *`, so `(%rdi)` is the actual `struct pt_regs` in memory.

But the first line `mov 0x70(%rdi),%rdi` changes `%rdi`, so how can I be used to decode the remaining registers, `%rsi`, `%rdx`, and `%rcx`, before calling `SyS_recv`?

Except from the LWN article:

```
asmlinkage long sys_recv(struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    return SyS_recv(regs->di, regs->si, regs->dx, regs->r10);
}
```

> The assembly of that function then becomes, in slightly reordered
> fashion:

```
<sys_recv>:
callq   <__fentry__>

/* decode regs->di, ->si, ->dx and ->r10 */
mov 0x70(%rdi),%rdi
mov 0x68(%rdi),%rsi
mov 0x60(%rdi),%rdx
mov 0x38(%rdi),%rcx

/* [ SyS_recv() is inlined here by the compiler, as it is tiny ] */
/* clear %r9 and %r8, the 5th and 6th args */
xor %r9d,%r9d
xor %r8d,%r8d

/* do the actual work */
callq   __sys_recvfrom

/* cleanup and return */
cltq
retq
```

Comment: The keyword being **reordered**. That's not the actual code, if you disassemble your kernel you will see `rdi` is loaded last.

Comment: I guess they wanted to make it more readable by using the outgoing argument ordering.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/zWYexeeYW) a simulated call that shows the correct order, if it may help.

Comment: That's and incredibly un-helpful way to present code to readers, without any comment about the RDI load being actually last.  Putting them in right-to-left order with RCX loaded first would have been a much better choice.

Comment: @Jester - why is it that `r10` gets decided into `rcx` (fourth argument)?

Comment: What I mean, why is `r10` given as the fourth argument to `SyS_recv`?

Comment: Because the system call interface uses `r10` for the 4th argument due to `syscall` instruction using `rcx` for the instruction pointer. The code converts from that to the normal ABI used by the C compiler.

Comment: @Jester Thanks. Didn’t knew that. Is it special for Linux, or is it the same for other OS’s too?

Comment: The `syscall` instruction itself is not OS specific.

Comment: @Jester But does the system call interface on every OS use `r10` for the 4th argument? Isn’t the system call interface part of the official AMD64 ABI? I think its weird that the `syscall` instruction uses `rcx` for the instruction pointer, when that information is available in `rip`, and the AMD64 ABI says that the 4th argument goes into `rcx`?

Comment: No, the information is not available in `rip` since `syscall` sets `rip` to the OS entry point address from the MSR. No, not every OS uses the same calling convention or ABI, e.g. microsoft windows.

Comment: @Jester - MSR? “calling convention” and “ABI” are referring to the same in your previous comment (not two different things)? I mean the calling convention is part of the ABI, right?

Comment: MSR=Model Specific Register. See the instruction set reference about how `syscall` works. It copies a preset value from a MSR into `rip`, effectively transferring control to a fixed location in the operating system.

Comment: @Jester But why does the ABI say that we should use `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, and `rcx` for the first four syscall arguments then? Is it because that works for `int 0x80` only and not for `syscall`, which expects the 4th argument to be in `r10`?